# Chrome extension passing form information to a PHP file

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension, forms, http-post

I am currently trying to create a simple extension that will get information from an HTML form and pass it to a PHP file adn then to a database. My manifest.json is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Sample Extension",
  "description": "Sample Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myScript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/*",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

My HTML file has this particular "form" element that I am trying to submit:

```html
<form action="http://localhost/FYP/index.php" method="POST">
    <div>
        <label> <b>Email Address</b> </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <label> <b>Password</b> </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input placeholder="Password" type="text" name="password" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign In">
    </div>
</form>
```

I am aware that there are more optimal ways of providing a login system, but at this point I am only trying to establish a connection and I will need to send information to my database in a similar way in the future as well. For now, I am trying to connect my HTML to my PHP file and it does not seem to be working. I tested the exact same code on a normal webpage and it worked, but it does not seem to do so for the extension. My PHP file simply returns the call:

```
<?php
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

However, currently nothing is being returned when the call is made and I get this error:
 [Call error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG92c.png)

I would really appreciate it if someone can point out my mistake as a beginner in creating extensions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code as follows:

**popup.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="popup.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="callphp">
                <div>
            <label> <b>Email Address</b> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Email" type="text" name="email" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> <b>Password</b> </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input placeholder="Password" type="text" name="password" >
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign In">
        </div>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Post your request using AJAX calls in seperate js file

```js
// POST the data to the server using XMLHttpRequest
function callPHP() {
    // Cancel the form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // The URL to POST our data to
    var postUrl = 'http://localhost/FYP/index.php';

    // Set up an asynchronous AJAX POST request
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', postUrl, true);

    // Prepare the data to be POSTed by URLEncoding each field's contents
    var email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('email').value);
    var password = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('password').value);
    
    var params = 'email=' + email + 
                 '&password=' + password;

    // Handle request state change events
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        
    };

    // Send the request and set status
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the request is now successfull and returns 200! However, the request payload is "email=some@email.com&password=somepassword", but the response doesn't have the information that is sent, it's only:

    array(0) {
}

Answer (score -1):

Use AJAX call to submit the form.